# No libclang.a after successfull build for iOS?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I've extracted official llvm/clang sources for 3.7 release, did some minor patching (`NSGetEnviron()`), configured and build for iOS with cmake:

```
cmake ../llvm_37_ios \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/llvm_37_ios_armv7_installed \
 -DLLVM_ENABLE_TERMINFO=OFF \
 -DLLVM_ENABLE_THREADS=OFF \
 -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk \
 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -arch armv7 -mios-version-min=8.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk" \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -arch armv7 -mios-version-min=8.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk" \
 -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True \
 -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=/Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/llvm_37_local_build/bin/llvm-tblgen \
 -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=/Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/llvm_37_local_build/bin/clang-tblgen \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="ARM;X86"
```

However i did not find `libclang.a` but found another `libclang*.a` libs:

```
MBA-Anton:llvm_37_ios_armv7_build asmirnov$ find . -name "libclang.a"
MBA-Anton:llvm_37_ios_armv7_build asmirnov$ find . -name "libclang*.a"
./lib/libclangBasic.a
./lib/libclangLex.a
./lib/libclangASTMatchers.a
./lib/libclangParse.a
./lib/libclangDynamicASTMatchers.a
./lib/libclangAnalysis.a
./lib/libclangEdit.a
./lib/libclangRewrite.a
./lib/libclangAST.a
./lib/libclangDriver.a
./lib/libclangCodeGen.a
./lib/libclangSerialization.a
./lib/libclangRewriteFrontend.a
./lib/libclangSema.a
./lib/libclangFrontendTool.a
./lib/libclangARCMigrate.a
./lib/libclangToolingCore.a
./lib/libclangFrontend.a
./lib/libclangIndex.a
./lib/libclangTooling.a
./lib/libclangFormat.a
./lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a
./lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a
./lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a
```

For some reason shared library was created but static was not:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/clang
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CIndexDiagnostic.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CIndexHigh.cpp.o
[ 98%] Built target clang
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CIndexInclusionStack.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CIndexUSRs.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CIndexer.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXComment.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXCursor.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXCompilationDatabase.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXLoadedDiagnostic.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXSourceLocation.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXStoredDiagnostic.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXString.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/CXType.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/IndexBody.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/IndexDecl.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/IndexTypeSourceInfo.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/Indexing.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/libclang/CMakeFiles/libclang.dir/IndexingContext.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../../../lib/libclang.dylib
[100%] Built target libclang
```

Did i miss something or it's clang configuration bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`libclang` is built as a shared library by default because it simplifies consumption from other languages such as Python using [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) or similar mechanisms.

To build a static library use `LIBCLANG_BUILD_STATIC` CMake option defined in `clang/tools/libclang/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option(LIBCLANG_BUILD_STATIC
  "Build libclang as a static library (in addition to a shared one)" OFF)
```

You can use it as follows:

```
cmake -DLIBCLANG_BUILD_STATIC=ON ...
```

Comment: i can confirm i was able to get `libclang.a`, thanks a lot! BTW, my original intent was to use Autotools but i was unable to find how to pass local tblgen paths for llvm/clang executables. How can that be done? my original script here: https://gist.github.com/4ntoine/d8155c06953b70dd95a5

Comment: @4ntoine I'm not sure how to do this with autotools, sorry.